# How can I simulate OFFSET in a MySQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, offset

I have a MySQL database table that contains an Article ID ( primary key ) and an Article Title.  I want to remove duplicate titles from the table, but keep the first occurrence of the title.  I initially simply did a query for all duplicate titles:

```
SELECT
    title,
    count( id ) AS count
FROM articles
GROUP BY title
HAVING count > 1
```

Then I replaced all the duplicate titles with a blank using a foreach loop and this command:

```
UPDATE articles
SET title = ''
WHERE title = '$duplicate_title'
```

I'd like to update the `articles` table and replace all duplicate titles except the first entry, based on the Article ID ASC using something like this.  The problem is that OFFSET doesn't seem to work in an UPDATE.  Is there a way to do this in a single query?

```
UPDATE articles
SET title = ''
WHERE title = '$duplicate_title'
ORDER BY id ASC
OFFSET 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE articles a
INNER JOIN articles b
    ON a.title = b.title AND a.ID > b.ID
SET title = '';
```

This basically says

> update all articles where there exists a matching article with the same title and a lower ID

Comment: Can you explain what the a and ? syntax does?  I've seen thing sort of 'trick' in other queries and I've been unable to understand it even after reading up on what's happening.

Comment: The `?` is a parameter placeholder generally used in [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) given a suitably sophisticated client (like PHP's PDO extension)

Comment: OK, I'm clear on the ? and PDO.  Now what does `UPDATE articles a` and `SELECT 1 FROM articles sub` do?  Specifically, I mean the `a` and the `sub`. Is that a shortcut for `articles as a` allowing us to access data from the outer query in the inner query without a conflict?

Comment: Yes, it's a table alias. The `AS` keyword is optional

Comment: I think I'm clear on the function.  Now I get this error, which seems to contradict what I thought I understood: `You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @T.BrianJones Ah, wasn't aware of this MySQL restriction. See my updated answer (tested too)

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that was a little outside the scope of my original question, but relevant nonetheless.

I already had a count of duplicates from the first query that found them.  I subtracted one from this count, then ordered my UPDATE query by ID DESC and then LIMITed the query to the count minus one.  This serves the same purpose and removes all duplicates except for the first entry.

Here is the UPDATE query I use:

```
UPDATE articles
SET title = ''
WHERE title = '$duplicate_title'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT $duplicate_count_minus_one
```